# JNI_VERSION_1_6 vs JNI_VERSION_1_4

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

Hello I'm maintaining an Android JNI library that uses JNI_VERSION_1_4.

I was wondering if I could change it to JNI_VERSION_1_6, but I didn't found any documentation explaining the differences between them.

Are they changing any function?
Is any one faster than the otherone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search [the JNI function reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for notes about when the function was added (e.g. *"SINCE: JDK/JRE 1.6"*). As far as I can tell, the only function added in 1.6 was `GetObjectRefType`.

That said, there's no real reason to return anything below 1_6 on Android.

Comment: One more question, the JNI lib is inside the android phone as lib?
If I have a very old phone could be possible that it is not able to load JNI_1_6?

Comment: The implementation of the JNI functions is part of the VM, in this case [Dalvik](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/froyo/vm/Jni.c) or Art. Android has supported `JNI_VERSION_1_6` as far back as Android 1.6 (aka Donut) - that's the oldest version I could find info for. At that point you're far more likely to get problems with SDK version incompatibilities than JNI version incompatibilities.